# Vuejs codes display curly braces at a glimpse when switching page, before a new page loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

i understand v-cloak is used to display nothing when a new page is loaded.

in my rails app, when i try to switch page (i am using vue component in Rails View), there is a short glimpse of Vuejs codes displaying curly braces before another new page is load. i am entirely baffled and not sure if this is turbolink related as there is no error message found in browser console, or in the rails git logs.

this short glimpse of Vuejs displaying curly braces before another page is loaded, is really annoying, can anyone help on this?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

v-cloak is used to do this.

[official API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#v-cloak)：

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
<div v-cloak>
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

tips: written [v-cloak] in @import loaded css file can't work for this problem.
another way:   around target tags.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using `[v-cloak]` which is a generic way of completely hiding an element until Vue inits, two more usable *"tools"* are `v-text` and `v-html` directives, coupled with computed properties delivering the strings the above directives expect from more complex logic.

Not only do they hide the content until init time, but they can also serve as selectors for the unparsed template elements, as they get removed from the element once Vue parses it. So you could apply backgrounds, `width`, `min-height`to those elements, without the need to spiff your layout with preload classes and remove them on `mounted()`.

An important note here is that `transition`s won't work on those elements, because Vue purposefully rebuilds the entire DOM of the template once it mounts. If it didn't, enter animations wouldn't work as expected. So there can be no `transition` from `h2[v-text]` to `h2`, because the element is completely replaced. But you can take that into account and start your `enter` transition from how the `[v-text]` element was styled.

It's probably not the solution you're looking for (it's more designer's work than programmer's, really) and it's definitely not a magical one liner: it has to be solved on a page by page basis.

But this is how pre-loaders are done (the technique is the same in any modern FE framework, it's just that sometimes you need to spiff your markup with preload classes and remove them on `mounted`, `ngAfterViewInit` or `componentDidMount`).

To be able to style this at your own pace, simply disable JavaScript (or don't init Vue, if you prefer) so you set every detail right. But don't overdo it.

Here's a basic example showing you don't need a whole lot of detail to get a decent effect. It's a matter of roughly matching element heights and coding in some striped CSS backgrounds, really (throw in a blur filter, if you want to get really fancy):

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

setTimeout(() => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
      Message: 'Message',
      Description: `<p>I'm baby tousled echo park pabst polaroid synth marfa. Migas small batch paleo pop-up street art, chia sriracha cronut ramps succulents portland. YOLO normcore taiyaki organic. Green juice helvetica single-origin coffee polaroid swag selvage schlitz. Artisan la croix unicorn cardigan meh everyday carry wolf thundercats.
      <p>Iceland hoodie vice, chicharrones gentrify dreamcatcher ethical jianbing blog truffaut pinterest VHS flannel selfies bushwick. Flannel activated charcoal bespoke master cleanse, chambray tumblr four loko helvetica chicharrones ugh aesthetic irony godard. Beard farm-to-table mumblecore wolf typewriter try-hard shoreditch church-key scenester tousled letterpress yuccie bitters. Selfies +1 man bun, jianbing hell of tote bag crucifix flexitarian. Cronut mumblecore knausgaard meditation authentic lumbersexual listicle pok pok coloring book pitchfork gentrify. +1 offal cronut, flexitarian glossier shoreditch biodiesel stumptown tumeric seitan polaroid.
      <p>Narwhal williamsburg adaptogen, four dollar toast retro chillwave occupy kombucha YOLO marfa franzen kogi biodiesel street art next level. Viral blog taxidermy twee echo park roof party. Hammock street art tumeric selvage sartorial. Paleo hashtag activated charcoal, heirloom quinoa cred blog ethical.`
    })
  })
}, 1000)
```

```css
#app h2[v-text] {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  height: 1em;
}

#app div[v-html] {
  min-height: 250px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    #fff,
    #fff 10px,
    #f5f5f5 10px,
    #f5f5f5 20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2 v-text="Message"></h2>
  <div v-html="Description"></div>
</div>
```

---

When applying this technique, do not use images, as they require loading as well. Work with CSS only and make sure that CSS is available in `<header>` (or at least before the app element). Last, but not least, keep in mind your preload has to match your app at all screen widths.